# Create a Java Date from a String and vise versa

Tags: java, string-conversion, java.util.date

I have a `date` in `Integer format`**(YYYYMMDD)**. And a `start_time` as a `String` **(HH:mm 24 hour system)**. and a `time_duration` in **hours** as a `double`.

```
int date = 20140214;
String start_time = "14:30";
double duration = 50.30;
```

I want to use these 3 values and create 2 Java Date Objects. One is `start_date` and one is `end_date`. They should be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`.

And then after I get 2 data Strings like  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`. how can I obtain those previous variables. `date`, `start_time`, `duration`.

This is my attempt.

```
public void solve() throws IOException {
    int date = 20140214;
    String start_time = "14:30";
    double duration = 24.50;
    String startDate = "";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    startDate = getDate(date) + " " + start_time;
    try {
        Date start_Date = df.parse(startDate);
        Date end_Date = new Date(start_Date.getTime()+(int)(duration*3600*1000));
        System.out.println(df.format(start_Date));
        System.out.println(df.format(end_Date));

    } catch (ParseException ex) {

    }

}
public String getDate(int dateInt) {
    String date = "";
    String dateIntString = String.valueOf(dateInt);
    date = date + dateIntString.substring(0, 4) + "-";
    date = date + dateIntString.substring(4, 6) + "-";
    date = date + dateIntString.substring(6, 8);
    return date;
}
```

Is there any easy way to do it. ? Or some built-in capabilities I can use other than those I have used ?

Comment: Please show us an attempt, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

## Strange Data Types For Date-Time

Using:

- An int to represent the digits of a calendar date
- A string to represent time-of-day digits
- A double to represent a duration of fractional hours

…are all unusual approaches. Probably not the wisest choices in handling date-time values.

## Avoid java.util.Date/Calendar

Know that the bundled classes java.util.Date and .Calendar are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). And get familiar with the handy [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

## Time Zone

Your question and example ignore the crucial issue of time zone. Handling date-time data without time zone is like handling text files without knowing their character encoding. Not good.

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to create time zone object. Avoid the non-standard 3-letter codes.

## Joda-Time

In Joda-Time, a DateTime object is similar to a java.util.Date object but actually knows its own assigned time zone.

Joda-Time offers three classes for representing spans of time: Period, [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), and Interval.

The [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class uses the "Half-Open" approach, where the beginning is inclusive and the ending is exclusive. This approach works well for handling spans of time and comparisons. Look for the handy `contains`, `abuts`, `overlap`, and `gap` methods.

```
int dateInput = 20140214;
String start_timeInput = "14:30";
double durationInput = 50.30;

// Clean up these inputs.
String datePortion = Integer.toString( dateInput );
String input = datePortion + " " + start_timeInput; 
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyyMMdd HH:mm");

// Specify the time zone this date-time represents.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ); // Or, DateTimeZone.UTC
DateTime dateTime = formatterInput.withZone( timeZone ).parseDateTime( input );

// Convert fractional hours to milliseconds, then milliseconds to a Duration object.
long millis = ( 60L * 60L * (long)(1000L * durationInput) ); // 1 hour = 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds.
Duration duration = new Duration( millis );

Interval interval = new Interval( dateTime, duration );

DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "MM" ).withLocale( Locale.FRANCE );
String description = "De " + formatterOutput.print( interval.getStart() ) + " à " + formatterOutput.print( interval.getEnd() );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "duration: " + duration ); // Format: PnYnMnDTnHnMnS (from ISO 8601)
System.out.println( "interval: " + interval ); // Format: <start>/<end> (from ISO 8601)
System.out.println( "description: " + description );
```

When run…

```
input: 20140214 14:30
dateTime: 2014-02-14T14:30:00.000+01:00
duration: PT181080S
interval: 2014-02-14T14:30:00.000+01:00/2014-02-16T16:48:00.000+01:00
description: De 14 févr. 2014 14:30:00 à 16 févr. 2014 16:48:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You have very many representations of date.

When in doubt, I usually head for getting to unix standard time (milliseconds since 1970) as soon as possible.

In this case it would be to convert the Integer date to a String, read out the four first as a year, two digits as month and the last two as day day, and then do the similar thing for the 24h time, and create a java.util.Date from this like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateParser=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm"); //please double check the syntax for this guy...
String yyyyMmDd = date.toString();
String fullDate = yyyyMmDd + " " + start_time;
java.util.Date startDate = dateParser.parse(fullDate);
long startTimeInMillis = startDate.getTime();
final long MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR = 1000*60*60;
long durationInMillis = (long)duration*MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
java.util.Date endDate = new java.util.Date(startTimeInMillis + durationInMillis);
```

Don't miss [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or Java 8 new, finally improved date handling named `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 you can write like
 int date = 20140214;
 String s=""+date;  
 Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(s);
```